# how to insert row to table adapter commit and update datagridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, tableadapter

I used the magic of c# to create a master detail form containing several datagridview controls. I have disabled editing and inserting rows to the datagrid view, and do it using a separate form instead. I take the user input from the form and call:

`awardsTableAdapter.Insert(100, 5, "test", DateTime.Now);`

This inserts and commits the row in the table, but doesn't refresh the datagridview. 
Note the 100 is the foreign key to the master form, i use txtId.Text to get the value, if there is a better way to get the PK of the current record in the master table please let me know. Also please help on how to make the new row appear in the datagridview.

Comment: How have you bound the Datagrid and its datasource?

Comment: yes. I have a dataset object containing all the data tables, table and adapters for each table

Comment: But you needa binding source that acts as a middle man between your datagrid and your datasource(s). Have you crated that object?

Comment: @Derek no, can u link to an example? I did everything using the wizard

Answer (score 1):

In order to get automatic updates in your `DataGridView` when the data has changed, you can use a `BindingSource` object.

Rather than wire up your DataGridView directly to the datasource do the following :-

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

bs.Datasource = YourDataSetObject;
```

Now you set the Datasource for your Datagrid as teh BindingSource object:-

```
dataGridView.Datasource = bs;
```

Hope this helps.